# Conceptually, why would you take the LN of LN?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Context:  The nature of base $e$.  The limit derivation of $e$ deals with continuous compounding.  In the physical world, nature and real life, percentage growth is often in "real time" and not artificial like monthly interest compounding.

So, let's discuss the graph of $y=ln(x)$   The theme of this graph is inverse exponential growth.  Like the Richter scale.  You need a huge increase in X to get an increase in Y.  f(3) is exponentially higher than f(2), etc.

Ran across this today $y=ln(ln(x))$ while playing around with some integrals.  What exactly does this mean?  When would a function need to take a log of an existing log function?

Comment: They can be very useful in asymptotic analysis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm for one example.

Comment: While $\sum_{n=1}^x \dfrac1x$ diverges slowly as $x$ increases without limit, close to $\ln x$, you can find $\sum_{n=2}^x \dfrac1{n \ln n}$ diverges more slowly, close to $\ln \ln x$, and $\sum_{n=2}^x \dfrac1{n (\ln n)(\ln \ln n)}$ even more slowly, close to $\ln \ln \ln x$, ...